# SQL query to find pairs with no values in common

Tags: database

I have a table which has columns **Person** and the **Food** of liking. The table is follows.

```
|----------|--------|
|   Person |Food    |
|----------|--------|
|   Sam    |Fish    |
|   Sam    |Taco    |
|   Alexis |Taco    |
|   Alexis |Pizza   |
|   Robert |Sushi   |
|   Robert |Chicken |
|----------|--------|
```

I want the pair of persons who have no common food. The output should be

```
|--------|--------|
|  Sam   | Robert |
| Alexis | Robert |
|--------|--------|
```

I am new to SQL. Could someone please point me in the right direction

Comment: This looks like homework. Is it?

Answer (score -1):

Hmmm . . . generate the pairs and then check that there is no food in common:

```
select p1.person, p2.person
from (select distinct person from liking) p1 join
     (select distinct person from liking) p2 
     on p1.person = p2.person left join
     liking l1
     on l1.person = p1.person left join
     liking l2
     on l2.person = p2.person and l2.food = l1.food
where l2.person is null
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if object_id('tempdb..#liking') is not null
    drop table #liking
create table #liking (person varchar(20), food varchar(20))
insert into #liking values ('Sam'   ,'fish'), ('sam', 'taco'), ('alexis' , 'taco'), ('alexis' , 'pizza'), ('robert', 'sushi'), ('robert','chicken')

select p1.person, p2.person, max(case when l1.food = l2.food then 1 else 0 end)
    from (select distinct person from #liking) p1 
cross join (select distinct person from #liking) p2 
left join #liking l1
    on l1.person = p1.person 
left join #liking l2
    on l2.person = p2.person
where p1.person>p2.person
group by p1.person, p2.person
having max(case when l1.food = l2.food then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: It would be nice if you provide some description for your solution.

Comment: Sorry about missing the explanation.

Comment: Explanation: cross join all combinations, use case statement to compare the food, grouped by each pair of people. Add p1.person>p2.person comparison to avoid duplicates in pairs x,y vs y,x which means the same for this problem. Finally use "having" to filter only when case statement returns 0 (no matching food for the pair).